# What is i(t) from circuit with differential equation?

Tags: circuit-analysis, differential

[image]

When t<0
Components in circuit are J<sub>t</sub> = 4 A, R1 = R2 = 2 Ω, R3 = 4 Ω ja L = 10 H

At t=0 switch K will be closed and i need to figure out what i<sub>L</sub>(t) is when t=4

So i tried to figure out i<sub>L</sub>(t) with  differential equation.
First i combined R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub> to get R<sub>12</sub>=1Ω 
Then i transformed power supply from current to voltage E<sub>t</sub>=J<sub>t</sub>*R<sub>12</sub>=J*1Ω =J
Then i combined R<sub>12</sub> and R<sub>3</sub> to get R<sub>z</sub>=5Ω
Now i can create equation which is 
$$E_t=L*\frac{di(t)}{dt}+R_ti(t)          $$
After adding constant i get
$$J_t=10*\frac{di(t)}{dt}+5i(t)          $$
First i found the roots
$$10r^t+5r=0 -> r=-\frac{1}{2}$$
So for homogeneous part i get $$y^h=C_1*(-\frac{1}{2})^t$$
And for nonhomogeneous part $$J_t=A$$
$$ \frac{dJ_t}{dt}=0 , \frac{d^2J_t}{dt^2}=0$$
So i get
$$  10*0+5=A->A=5  $$ 
For complete equation i get
$$ y(t)=C_1*(-\frac{1}{2})^t+5  $$
To figure out what is C<sub>1</sub> i use t=0
$$ y(0)=C_1*(-\frac{1}{2})^0+5=4 ->C_1=-1  $$
And now for t=4 i get 
$$ y(4)=-1*(-\frac{1}{2})^4+5=4.5   $$
I know this answer isn't correct but i don't know what went wrong
Also sorry if its little bit hard to read this, i'm new to this

Comment: You've solved the differential equation incorrectly. The solution should be an exponential function. The simple method is to analyze the circuit at steady-state before and after the switch closes. In steady-state before t=0, what's the current \$i_L\$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to form the homogeneous solution is (not what you have given in the fourth equation):
$${i_L}_h=C_1*e^{(-\frac{1}{2})t}$$
(Your differential equation is written for \$i_L(t)\$, it is better not to change it to \$y\$ midstream.)

For t>0, without knowing \$J\$, you cannot solve \$i_L(t)\$. The only specification of \$J\$ given is that it is 4. So a forced assumption is that \$J = 4\$ for all time if you want a solution from what are given.

With \$J\$ being constant, by inspection, $$i_L(t) = \frac{J_t}{5} $$ is a particular solution to the differential equation. You can plug that into your second equation to confirm.

Now the complete solution becomes:
$$i_L(t)=C_1*e^{(-\frac{1}{2})t} + \frac{J_t}{5}$$

Now you need the initial condition of \$i_L(0)\$ to solve for the constant \$C_1\$. Given \$J\$ is constant and assuming steady state at t=0, \$L\$ behaves as a short circuit at t=0. Therefore, the only elements left in the schematic for figuring out the initial condition are \$J,\ R_2,\ R_3\$, a simple current divider.